# How to add any symbol instead another symbol in string C++?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a "Hangman" game console application and I want to add a symbol instead of another symbol in the string.

I tried erase,remove and replace functions,but it isn't working for me. Because I have a symbol in a const char* and I cannot convert it to char.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
string conceivedword;
string hint;
string choice;
string first_player_word;
string characterstring;
int counter = 0;
void first_player() {
    cout << "Welcome to Hangman! //Firstgamerzone " << endl;
    cout << "Please conceive the word" << endl;
    getline(cin, conceivedword);
    cout << "Type the hint" << endl;
    getline(cin, hint);
    system("cls");
    cout << " The hint is: " << hint << endl;
}
void second_player() {
    while (0 == 0) {
        cout << "Are you inputting word or character?" << endl;
        //while (0 == 0) {
        getline(cin, choice);
        if (choice == "word" || choice == "sitkva" || choice == "sityva") {
            cin >> first_player_word;
            if (first_player_word == conceivedword) {
                cout << "Congrats! You're winner! shen moige gazqura :D " << endl;
                break;
            }
            else {
                counter += 1;
                if (counter > 5) {
                    cout << "Bad luck. You lost. You had only 5 attempts." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                cout << "Bad luck. Try again" << endl;
                //second_player();
            }
        }
        else if (choice == "character" || choice == "aso") {
            cin >> characterstring;
            if (characterstring.length() > 1) cout << "Hey,Your Lier! You lost." << endl;
            else {
                counter += 1;
                const char *character = characterstring.c_str();
                int exists = conceivedword.find(character);
                //cout << exists << endl;
                int index = conceivedword.find(character);
                if (exists > 0) {
                    if (counter > 5) {
                        cout << "You lost. You had only 5 attempts" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    cout << "Right. You rock: " << endl;
                    int length = conceivedword.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < conceivedword.length(); i++) {
                        if (i == index) {

                            cout << character;
                            //replace(conceivedword.begin(), conceivedword.end(), '_', character);
                        }
                            //cout << conceivedword.length() << endl;
                        //if (i == index) {
                            //replace(conceivedword.begin(), conceivedword.end(), '_', '*');
                            //}
                        cout << "_" << " ";
                        //cout << endl;
                    }
                    second_player();
                    cout << endl;
                }
                if(exists <= 0) {
                    cout << "Not right. Try again" << endl;
                    second_player();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    system("Color 3");
    first_player();
    second_player();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

replace function isn't working so far.

Comment: `std::string::replace` maybe? It's hard to tell what you want exactly. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your non-working code and a clear problem statement (hint: example inputs and outputs help).

Comment: Always a piece of code can make it easier to help.

Comment: You should post MCVE

Comment: I don't know what is MCVE.

Comment: @GùrìCôppérfîéld http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edited it if you wanted the whole code. I think I write maximum of my problem.

Comment: The maximum is not what we're looking for. You're looking at `replace()` not working for you. To demonstrate that, a five-liner should be sufficient. Posting your whole "Hangman" basically shows a lack of research effort on your part, and just increases the chances of the error being elsewhere (something *you* should have ruled out first).

Comment: I posted the small code,which was enough I think. But Slava tell me that he wants MCVE. I have no idea what to do so far.

Comment: The first character (which is the `char` you're interested in) in `character` is `character[0]`. But since you're only interested in one character, use only that character: `char character = characterstring[0];`.

Comment: "You're winner!" and "Your Lier" don't make sense.

Comment: You lier equals the lose in my program.

Comment: Part of asking for help is giving the people that are willing to help you what they want.  You should be able to split out the way to want to replace a character into its own compilable code to verify that is where you are having the issue.  This is part of programming and you should get used to.

Comment: #molbdnilo It converts. But I wrote : char boom = conceivedword[index]. But it isn't working with replace function.

Comment: I have to say again. I posted the small and maximum understandable code. But Slava told me that I should posted the MCVE. Soo..

Comment: @GùrìCôppérfîéld yes I did and you did not post MCVE before not now, before it was not compilable (not complete), now it is not minimal. Looking into your code it is difficult to say what is wrong there, it is easier to say what is right.

Comment: @guricopperfield mvce doesn't mean posting all your code, nor does it mean posting 5 random lines which you suspect causing problems. Mvce means you take those 5 random lines and research them in a separate empty console application. During your research you might write some more code to get those 5 lines to compile and produce the error that has been bugging you. The mvce is all te code in that new project.

Comment: @GùrìCôppérfîéld: I would seriously suggest you **follow** the provided link explaining what a MCVE is, exactly. **Creating** a MCVE is a very useful debugging technique, which quite often helps to identify an error yourself long before you actually post anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace characters in string. What you should do is to use std::string as std::vector< char > (because it's really similar).

You can assign letters to some place in your word:

> word[2] = yourLetter;

You dont even need to know what was in that place before, so you don't need to replace it - assigning is easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want more people like you.